# How to prevent form submission using jquery if validation fails

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, validation

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var WPJB = WPJB || {};
      $("#clickandpledge_cardNumber").on("keypress keyup blur",function(event) {    
            $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\d].+/, ""));
            if ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
            }); 
            $("#clickandpledge_cvc").on("keypress keyup blur",function(event) {    
            $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\d].+/, ""));
            if ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
            });
       jQuery('.wpjb-place-order').click(function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       var $form = jQuery('.wpjb-place-order'); 
       var paymentmethod = $("input[name=cnp_payment_method_selection]:checked").val();
       var focusSet = false;
       if(paymentmethod == 'CreditCard')
       {

            if($("input[name=clickandpledge_onetimeonly]:checked").val() == "clickandpledge_OneTimeOnly")
            {
            if($('#clickandpledge_nameOnCard').val() == '' && $('#clickandpledge_cardNumber').val() == '' && $('#clickandpledge_cvc').val() == '')
            {
            if($("#clickandpledge_nameOnCard").parent().next(".validation").length == 0) // only add if not added
            {
            alert('Please Enter Required fields');
            }           
            $.preventDefault(); // prevent form from POST to server
            $('#clickandpledge_nameOnCard').focus();
            focusSet = true;
            //return false;
            }
            // Name on Card 
            if($('#clickandpledge_nameOnCard').val() == '')
            {
            if($("#clickandpledge_nameOnCard").parent().next(".validation").length == 0) // only add if not added
            {
            alert('Please Enter name on card'); 
            //$("#clickandpledge_nameOnCard").parent().after("<div class='validation' style='color:red;margin-bottom: 20px;'>Please enter Name on Card</div>");
            }
            $.preventDefault(); // prevent form from POST to server
            $('#clickandpledge_nameOnCard').focus();
            focusSet = true;
            //return false;
            } 
            else if($('#clickandpledge_nameOnCard').val() != '')
            {

            }
            else 
            {
            $("#clickandpledge_nameOnCard").parent().next(".validation").remove(); // remove it
            }
            // Credit Card Number
            if($('#clickandpledge_cardNumber').val() == '')
            {
            if($("#clickandpledge_cardNumber").parent().next(".validation").length == 0) // only add if not added
            {
            alert('Please Enter Card number');  
            //$("#clickandpledge_cardNumber").parent().after("<div class='validation' style='color:red;margin-bottom: 20px;'>Please enter Credit Card number</div>");
            }
            $.preventDefault(); // prevent form from POST to server
            $('#clickandpledge_cardNumber').focus();
            focusSet = true;
            //return false;
            } 
            else if($('#clickandpledge_cardNumber').val() != '')
            {

            }
            else 
            {
            $("#clickandpledge_cardNumber").parent().next(".validation").remove(); // remove it
            }
            // Credit CVV
            if($('#clickandpledge_cvc').val() == '')
            {
            if($("#clickandpledge_cvc").parent().next(".validation").length == 0) // only add if not added
            {
            alert('Please Enter CVV of Card');
            //$("#clickandpledge_cvc").parent().after("<div class='validation' style='color:red;margin-bottom: 20px;'>Please enter CVV</div>");
            }
            $.preventDefault(); // prevent form from POST to server
            $('#clickandpledge_cvc').focus();
            focusSet = true;
            //return false;
            } 
            else if($('#clickandpledge_cvc').val() != '')
            {

            }
            else 
            {
            $("#clickandpledge_cvc").parent().next(".validation").remove(); // remove it
            }           

            }   
            else 
            {
    // Name on Card 
            if($('#clickandpledge_nameOnCard').val() == '')
            {
            if($("#clickandpledge_nameOnCard").parent().next(".validation").length == 0) // only add if not added
            {
            $("#clickandpledge_nameOnCard").parent().after("<div class='validation' style='color:red;margin-bottom: 20px;'>Please enter Name on Card</div>");
            }
            $.preventDefault(); // prevent form from POST to server
            $('#clickandpledge_nameOnCard').focus();
            focusSet = true;
            //return false;
            } 
            else if($('#clickandpledge_nameOnCard').val() != '')
            {

            }
            else 
            {
            $("#clickandpledge_nameOnCard").parent().next(".validation").remove(); // remove it
            }
            // Credit Card Number
            if($('#clickandpledge_cardNumber').val() == '')
            {
            if($("#clickandpledge_cardNumber").parent().next(".validation").length == 0) // only add if not added
            {
            $("#clickandpledge_cardNumber").parent().after("<div class='validation' style='color:red;margin-bottom: 20px;'>Please enter Credit Card number</div>");
            }
            $.preventDefault(); // prevent form from POST to server
            $('#clickandpledge_cardNumber').focus();
            focusSet = true;
            //return false;
            } 
            else if($('#clickandpledge_cardNumber').val() != '')
            {

            }
            else 
            {
            $("#clickandpledge_cardNumber").parent().next(".validation").remove(); // remove it
            }
            // Credit CVV
            if($('#clickandpledge_cvc').val() == '')
            {
            if($("#clickandpledge_cvc").parent().next(".validation").length == 0) // only add if not added
            {
            $("#clickandpledge_cvc").parent().after("<div class='validation' style='color:red;margin-bottom: 20px;'>Please enter CVV</div>");
            }
            $.preventDefault(); // prevent form from POST to server
            $('#clickandpledge_cvc').focus();
            focusSet = true;
            //return false;
            } 
            else if($('#clickandpledge_cvc').val() != '')
            {

            }
            else 
            {
            $("#clickandpledge_cvc").parent().next(".validation").remove(); // remove it
            }           
}   
       }   
       else if(paymentmethod == 'eCheck')
       {
            // Routing number
            if($('#clickandpledge_echeck_RoutingNumber').val() == '')
            {
            if($("#clickandpledge_echeck_RoutingNumber").parent().next(".validation").length == 0) // only add if not added
            {
            alert('Please enter Routing Number');   
            //$("#clickandpledge_echeck_RoutingNumber").parent().after("<div class='validation' style='color:red;margin-bottom: 20px;'>Please enter Routing Number</div>");
            }
            $.preventDefault(); // prevent form from POST to server
            $('#clickandpledge_echeck_RoutingNumber').focus();
            focusSet = true;
            //return false;
            } 
            else if($('#clickandpledge_echeck_RoutingNumber').val() != '')
            {

            }
            else 
            {
            $("#clickandpledge_echeck_RoutingNumber").parent().next(".validation").remove(); // remove it
            } 
            // Check Numbre 
            if($('#clickandpledge_echeck_CheckNumber').val() == '')
            {
            if($("#clickandpledge_echeck_CheckNumber").parent().next(".validation").length == 0) // only add if not added
            {
            alert('Please enter Check Number');
            //$("#clickandpledge_echeck_CheckNumber").parent().after("<div class='validation' style='color:red;margin-bottom: 20px;'>Please enter Routing Number</div>");
            }
            $.preventDefault(); // prevent form from POST to server
            $('#clickandpledge_echeck_CheckNumber').focus();
            focusSet = true;
            //return false;
            } 
            else if($('#clickandpledge_echeck_CheckNumber').val() != '')
            {

            }
            else 
            {
            $("#clickandpledge_echeck_CheckNumber").parent().next(".validation").remove(); // remove it
            } 
            // Account Number 
            if($('#clickandpledge_echeck_AccountNumber').val() == '')
            {
            if($("#clickandpledge_echeck_AccountNumber").parent().next(".validation").length == 0) // only add if not added
            {
            alert('Please enter Account Number');
            //$("#clickandpledge_echeck_AccountNumber").parent().after("<div class='validation' style='color:red;margin-bottom: 20px;'>Please enter Routing Number</div>");
            }
            $.preventDefault(); // prevent form from POST to server
            $('#clickandpledge_echeck_AccountNumber').focus();
            focusSet = true;
            //return false;
            } 
            else if($('#clickandpledge_echeck_AccountNumber').val() != '')
            {

            }
            else 
            {
                $("#clickandpledge_echeck_AccountNumber").parent().next(".validation").remove(); // remove it
            }
            // RE-type Account Number   
            if($('#clickandpledge_echeck_retypeAccountNumber').val() == '')
            {
            if($("#clickandpledge_echeck_retypeAccountNumber").parent().next(".validation").length == 0) // only add if not added
            {
            alert('Please re-enter Account Number');    
            //$("#clickandpledge_echeck_retypeAccountNumber").parent().after("<div class='validation' style='color:red;margin-bottom: 20px;'>Please enter Routing Number</div>");
            }
            $.preventDefault(); // prevent form from POST to server
            $('#clickandpledge_echeck_retypeAccountNumber').focus();
            focusSet = true;
            //return false;
            } 
            else if($('#clickandpledge_echeck_retypeAccountNumber').val() != '')
            {

            }
            else 
            {
            $("#clickandpledge_echeck_retypeAccountNumber").parent().next(".validation").remove(); // remove it
            }
            //  Name on Account eCheck
            if($('#clickandpledge_echeck_NameOnAccount').val() == '')
            {
            if($("#clickandpledge_echeck_NameOnAccount").parent().next(".validation").length == 0) // only add if not added
            {
            alert('Please enter Name on Account');  
            //$("#clickandpledge_echeck_NameOnAccount").parent().after("<div class='validation' style='color:red;margin-bottom: 20px;'>Please enter Routing Number</div>");
            }
            $.preventDefault(); // prevent form from POST to server
            $('#clickandpledge_echeck_NameOnAccount').focus();
            focusSet = true;
            //return false;
            } 
            else if($('#clickandpledge_echeck_NameOnAccount').val() != '')
            {

            }
            else 
            {
                $("#clickandpledge_echeck_NameOnAccount").parent().next(".validation").remove(); // remove it
            }           
       } else
       {

       }    
            $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);
            clickandpledgeTransaction();        
            return false;
    });
```

I am using above to form validate and submit , validation empty working , and while alert `"OK"` submit button also submitting , it should not submit and prevent the form submission i am unable to handle this request when fails validation..

My main problem is when validation fails form should not submit..if validation fails i am getting alert message when says **ok** the button of automatically submitting..

Comment: onsubmit return false

Comment: You should really look at using jQuery validate. It will solve your problem and turn all that code in to about 10 lines.

Comment: you can edit your question to highlight your problem.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I agree its even easy to use

Comment: on your form tag add `onsubmit="return false"`

Comment: we dont have any form tag we have only input added, because form also taken by third party plugin

Answer (score 0):

Jquery.validate is a best way to validate all fields before submitting

Try  this:

```
<script>

    $("#form").validate({
        errorElement: "em",
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {

            $(element.parent("div").addClass("form-animate-error"));
            error.appendTo(element.parent("div"));
        },
        success: function (label) {
            $(label.parent("div").removeClass("form-animate-error"));
        },
        rules: {
            txtTitle: "required",
            validate_lastname: "required",
            validate_username: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            validate_password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            validate_confirm_password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                equalTo: "#validate_password"
            },
            validate_email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            validate_agree: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            City: "Please select city",
            PropertyType: "Please select property type",
          //  ParkingType: "Please select parking type",
            validate_firstname: "Please enter your firstname",
            validate_lastname: "Please enter your lastname",
            validate_username: {
                required: "Please enter a username",
                minlength: "Your username must consist of at least 2 characters"
            },
            validate_password: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
            },
            validate_confirm_password: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long",
                equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
            },
            validate_email: "Please enter a valid email address",
            validate_agree: "Please accept our policy"
        }
    });
</script>
```